# Why my Child component cant access to redux store, if parent can?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my component PreviewCard I can get data from redux store (useSelector works), but when we move into PreviewCard's child component I get an error (could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a `<Provider>`)

[image: error screen]

I try to wrap MyDoc in another provider with store, but it doesnt help

```
const PreviewCard = () => {
 //useSelector works here!
  return (
    <div>
      <PDFViewer style= {{width: '100%', height: '90vh'}}>
        <MyDoc /> //myChild component useSelector is not working inside it
      </PDFViewer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const MyDoc = () => {
  
  const formStore = useSelector(state => state.pdfFormReducer) // error here!
  return (
   <Document>
     <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
         //just some layout for pdf
     </Page>
   </Document>
```

Comment: Can you please add the code snippet of the child component?

Comment: Can you please show us how are you wrapping your main component with `<Provider>` and exporting it. There seems to be an issue there.

Comment: What is the purpose of the PDFViewer component @46kvolamak?

Comment: @ArslanShahan problem was in PDFViewer wrapper from react-pdf library. It blocks access to provider

Comment: @Aswin_Pradeep yeah, problem in PDFViewer. it renders pdf file on web page. Do i need to make custom redux wrapper for PDFViewer or what? i still dont know

Comment: I am not sure what is the right approach to be followed. But one simple workaround if the purpose of the pdf viewer is to show something then the data that is to be shown can be passed as props to the MyDoc component from PreviewCard where we have access to the store.