# Why cant use redux hooks at child component?

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, expo, provider

I've same error of that [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68342289/why-my-child-component-cant-access-to-redux-store-if-parent-can),
i've a Redux provider from a react-native app,
i can use Redux hooks ([useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector-examples), [useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch)) from a component but in child of same component
i cant use Redux hooks with error message:

`Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>`

With this call stack:

```
This error is located at:
    in MusicDetails (created by SearchItemDetails) <- Error component try call: useDispatch
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Surface)
    in Surface
    in ThemedComponent (created by withTheme(Surface))
    in withTheme(Surface) (created by SearchItemDetails)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Surface)
    in Surface
    in ThemedComponent (created by withTheme(Surface))
    in withTheme(Surface) (created by Modal)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Modal)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Modal)
    in Modal (created by SearchItemDetails) <- Parent component can use hooks Redux
    in ThemeProvider <- Theme Provider
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by PortalManager)
    in PortalManager (created by Portal.Host)
    in Portal.Host (created by Provider)
    in Provider (created by App) <- Redux Provider
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
```

component App.tsx (top level Root):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import DatabaseContext, {database} from './src/Context/DatabaseContext';

import createSqliteTable from './src/libs/create-sqlite-tables';
import Routing from './src/components/Routing';
import { Provider as ThemeProvider, DarkTheme, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native-paper';
import {Provider as ReduxProvider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './src/store'
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  const [isPrePending, setIsPrePending] = React.useState(true);
  const isPrePendingError = React.useRef<boolean>(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    createSqliteTable(database)
    .catch(error => {
      isPrePendingError.current = true;
      console.log("> create SQLite tables has fail with: ", error);
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("> SQLite tables has been created.")
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setIsPrePending(false);
    })
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <StatusBar style="auto" translucent={false} />

    <DatabaseContext.Provider value={database}>

      <ThemeProvider theme={DarkTheme}>

        <ReduxProvider store={store}>
          {isPrePending ? (
            <View style={{
              flex: 1,
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center"
            }}>
              <ActivityIndicator animating size={32} />
            </View>
          ): <Routing />}
        </ReduxProvider>

      </ThemeProvider>

    </DatabaseContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

the SearchItemDetails component:

- child of Routing component
- parent of MusicDetails component

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Modal, Portal, Surface } from 'react-native-paper';
import type { AlbumPreviewAPI, ArtistPreviewAPI, MusicVideoAPI } from '../../api/ytm-api';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from '../../hooks/redux';
import { createCancel } from '../../store/actions/searchDetailsActions';
import { SearchDetailsState } from '../../store/reducers/searchDetailsReducers';
import AlbumDetails from '../AlbumDetails/AlbumDetails';
import ArtistDetails from '../ArtistDetails/ArtistDetails';
import MusicDetails from '../MusicDetails/MusicDetails';
import styles from '../styles';

interface SearchItemDetailsProps {

}

const SearchItemDetails: React.FC<SearchItemDetailsProps> = () => {

  const searchDetails = useAppSelector(state => state.searchDetails); // hooks work
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch(); // hooks work

  const isAlbum = (details: SearchDetailsState): details is AlbumPreviewAPI => (
    !!(details as AlbumPreviewAPI)?.albumId
  );
  const isArtist = (details: SearchDetailsState): details is ArtistPreviewAPI => (
    !!(details as ArtistPreviewAPI)?.artistId
  );
  const isMusic = (details: SearchDetailsState): details is MusicVideoAPI => (
    !!(details as MusicVideoAPI)?.youtubeId
  );

  const getComponent = (details: SearchDetailsState | null = null): React.ElementType<{
    onClose: () => void;
    item: any
  }> | never => {

    if(!details) {
      return React.Fragment;
    }

    if(isAlbum(details)) {
      return AlbumDetails;
    } else if(isArtist(details)) {
      return ArtistDetails;
    } else if(isMusic(details)) {
      return MusicDetails;
    } else {
      throw new Error(`cant render SearchItemDetails because never find item category`);
    }
  }

  const Component = getComponent(searchDetails);

  const onCancelDetails = () => {
    dispatch(createCancel());
  }


  return (
    <Portal>
      <Modal visible={!!searchDetails} onDismiss={onCancelDetails}>
        <Surface style={styles.modalContainer}>
          {!!searchDetails && <Component onClose={onCancelDetails} item={searchDetails} />}
        </Surface>
      </Modal>
    </Portal>
  );
}

export default SearchItemDetails;
```

And the MusicDetails component (cant use Redux hooks):

- child of SearchItemDetails

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, Image, View } from 'react-native';
import { IconButton } from 'react-native-paper';
import { useAppDispatch } from '../../hooks/redux';
import useSelectPlaylist from '../../hooks/useSelectPlaylist';
import { createAddDownload } from '../../store/actions/downloadReducers';
import ArtistInline from '../ArtistInline/ArtistInline';
import ModalHeader from '../ModalHeader/ModalHeader';
import api, {ArtistAPI, GetArtistAPI, MusicVideoAPI} from './../../api/ytm-api';

interface MusicDetailsProps {
  item: MusicVideoAPI;
  onClose: () => void;
}

const MusicDetails: React.FC<MusicDetailsProps> = ({
  item,
  onClose
}) => {

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch(); // NOT WORK!!
  // Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

  const artistsRef = React.useRef<ArtistAPI[]>([]);
  const abortArtists = React.useRef<AbortController>(new AbortController());

  const { onOpen, playlist, render } = useSelectPlaylist({
    musicTitle: item.title || ""
  })

  const [isPendingArtists, setIsPendingArtists] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {

    if(!item.artists?.length) {
      return;
    }

    setIsPendingArtists(true);

    abortArtists.current = new AbortController();

    Promise.all(item.artists.map(artist => (
      api.getArtist(artist.id || "", {signal: abortArtists.current.signal})
    )))
    .then((responses: GetArtistAPI[]) => {
      artistsRef.current = responses.map(response => response.artist);
    })
    .catch(firstError => {
      console.log(`> cant fetch artists with ${firstError.code} => ${firstError.message}`);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setIsPendingArtists(false);
    })

    return () => {
      abortArtists.current.abort();
    }

  }, [item]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(playlist !== null) {
      onDownload(playlist);
    }
  }, [playlist])

  const onDownload = (playlist: {id: number, name: string}) => {

    console.log(`@TODO: dispatch download with (
      youtubeId: ${item.youtubeId},
      ownerName: ${artistsRef?.current[0].name},
      remote: ${api.getStreamUrl(item.youtubeId || "")},
      title: ${item.title},
      thumbnail: ${item.thumbnailUrl},
      playlistId: ${playlist.id},
      ownerThumbnail: ${(artistsRef?.current[0].thumbnails && artistsRef?.current[0].thumbnails.length > 0 ) ? artistsRef?.current[0].thumbnails[0].url: undefined}
    )`)

    // dispatch(createAddDownload({
    //   youtubeId: item.youtubeId || "",
    //   ownerName: artistsRef?.current[0].name || "",
    //   remote: api.getStreamUrl(item.youtubeId || ""),
    //   title: item.title || "",
    //   thumbnail: item.thumbnailUrl,
    //   playlistId: playlist.id,
    //   ownerThumbnail: (artistsRef?.current[0].thumbnails && artistsRef?.current[0].thumbnails.length > 0 ) ? artistsRef?.current[0].thumbnails[0].url: undefined
    // }))
  }

  return (
    <>
    <ModalHeader title={item.title || ""} subtitle={item.album} onClose={onClose} />

    <View style={{marginVertical: 4}}>
      <View style={{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        flexDirection: "row",
      }}>
        <View style={{
          position: "relative"
        }}>
          <Image style={{width: 96, height: 96}} source={{uri: item.thumbnailUrl}} />

          <View style={{
            position: "absolute",
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            top: 0,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.6)",
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center"
          }}>
            <IconButton icon="download" size={24} onPress={onOpen} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>

      <View>
        {isPendingArtists ? (
          <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            marginVertical: 4
          }}>
            <ActivityIndicator animating size={16} />
          </View>
        ): (
          <View style={{
            marginVertical: 4
          }}>
            {artistsRef.current?.map(artist => (
              <ArtistInline artist={artist} key={artist.artistId} />
            ))}
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    </View>

    {render}
    </>
  );
}

export default MusicDetails;
```

From my current structure my component `MusicDetails` is really a child of `ReduxProvider`,
why i cant use redux hooks from this component ?

Redux hooks are imports from local file because i've import default hook and re export with type hint:

hooks/redux.ts:

```js
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './../store'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

I've just follow documentation about [using with typescript](https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#define-typed-hooks) for that.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with these libraries, but the react-native-paper documentation has a note about using it with redux: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/getting-started.html#usage

Comment: Component `SearchItemDetails ` use a child Component `Portal` from [react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/portal.html) that allow feature Modal component. I've try remove Portal Component and this is work i can use my hooks Redux. But my modal dont work. I've posted a [issue at react-native-paper](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/3229) Portal "allow" render at a different place in the parent tree. I think Portal render my child Component outside my ReduxProvider.

Comment: @y2bd Yes, I a solve that, from you link about using redux with `react-native-paper` him ask render of `redux provider` before `theme provider`.
This is caused my issue.
Thank for your time.

Comment: Please mark the question as solved